# Trying to get a count of fornames which begin with eithe M or A I get right answer but is not perfect

Tags: sql

```
SELECT COUNT(SUBSTR(forenames,1,1))
FROM employee
WHERE
    (SUBSTR(forenames,1,1) like '%M%')
OR
    (SUBSTR(forenames,1,1) like '%A%')
```

Comment: Please change the title of this post and add a question and more information.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @Mark Byers: I could see the use for determining table partitioning boundary points.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
   COUNT(forenames)
FROM
   employee
WHERE
   forenames like 'M%'
   OR forenames like 'A%'
```

Comment: Could also have used.... Where forenames like '[AM]%' Looks like you would get the same results and the same execution plan.

Comment: Nice one G. I also suggested a variation to APC's one below.

Answer (score 0):

Straightforward count:

```
select count(*)
from   employee 
where  substr(forenames,1,1) in ('A', 'M') 
/
```

If you want to know number of each initial that would be :

```
select substr(forenames,1,1)
       , count(*)
from   employee 
where substr(forenames,1,1) in ('A', 'M') 
group by substr(forenames,1,1) 
/
```

Comment: Also:
select count(*)
from   employee 
where  left(forenames,1) in ('A', 'M')

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what database this is for.
That said, this is a job for regex.  Performing evaluations based on the results of a function performed on a column IE:

```
SUBSTR(forenames, 1, 1) LIKE '%M%'
```

...means that if an index exists on the column - the index can't be used even if the optimizer wanted to.  Wildcarding the left side in a `LIKE` will also stop an index from being used.

### MySQL

---

Use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM EMPLOYEE e
 WHERE e.forenames REGEXP '^[AM]'
```

Reference:

- [MySQL Documentation: 11.4.2. Regular Expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html)

### SQL Server

---

For SQL Server 2000, check [this article regarding adding regex support](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/regular-expressions-in-t-sql).  SQL Server 2005+, [you have to enable CLR functions & write a CLR function that will allow you to execute regexes against column values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx).

SQL Server 2005+ example:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM EMPLOYEE e
 WHERE dbo.RegexMatch(e.forenames, N'^[AM]') = 0
```

### Oracle

---

Oracle 10g+ supports regular expressions - use the [REGEXP_LIKE](http://www.psoug.org/reference/regexp.html) for this case:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM EMPLOYEE e
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(e.forenames, '^[AM]')
```